# VBA Word Insert text dynamically - Problems with ContentControl - Alternatives?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I am struggling quite a bit with ContentControl(s) in my Word VBA project.
There are a number of content control text fields which all have the same name (they have the same name because at the beginning the total number of required fields is not known, so I copy and paste the fields as many times as required). Now I want to loop through the content control fields and change the name of the fields based on the index of the individual items (e.g. first field in the document = "One", second field in the document = "two" and so on).

However, as mentioned in other threads, the index of the content control element does not correspond to its position in the document (I do not know, what it corresponds to).
Thus, instead of getting the fields in order, I get e.g. "four" --> "one" --> "three" --> "two" (or any other possible combination).

The content of the fields is coming from UserForm TextBoxes. The text boxes are named Text_Box_1 to Text_Box_4:

```
Private Sub Test() 'Note: The actual code is more complex, this is just to demonstrate my problem.

Dim i As Integer

UserForm1.TextBox1 = "one"
UserForm1.TextBox2 = "two"
UserForm1.TextBox3 = "three"
UserForm1.TextBox4 = "four"    

For i = 1 To 4 - 1 'Since there are four text boxes in the UserForm in this example, the text snippet containing the text field gets copied and pasted three times; Note: Here the number of textboxes is pre-determined and fixed, in the actual project, it is variable.
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Index:="Copy").Range.Copy '
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Index:="Paste").Range.Paste
Next i

For i = 1 To 4 'This code is supposed to loop through the four content control text fields and insert text from the corresponding UserForm text box. However, content control text field 1, unfortunately does no correspond to UserForm.TextBox1 for some reason.
    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Number").Item(i).Range.Text = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & i)
Next i

End Sub
```

[Before running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H0yK.jpg)

[After runnning the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiMSk.jpg)

Is there any way to name to content control fields in the right order?
If not, what would be an alternative method to achieve my goals.
I think legacy text fields are not an option, since the document has to be protected; I have not looked into ActiveX text fields too much; Text boxes (shapes) might be another option, but they might have their own drawbacks.

It is really frustrating that the content control fields are behaving so weirdly and that something seemingly very simple and straight-forward can be so complicated (at least for me).

edit: Fixed a typo in the title.

Comment: Content control index #s for a given title are assigned according to the order in which they are inserted. If you assign tags to them, you can keep the titles constant and test the tag values.You may also be interested in: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/27809-code-add-new-row-table.html#post87989, https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/13955-macro-add-row-table-word-form.html#post38461, & https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43603-multiple-dependent-dropdown-lists-table-add-new.html#post145675

Comment: Are you sure about the order? I get a different order every time I execute my code, so it does not not seem to be the order of insertion. I'll check out your links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use copy and paste I would insert the required text and content controls in my routine, something like this.

```
Private Sub Test()

   Dim i As Integer

   UserForm1.TextBox1 = "one"
   UserForm1.TextBox2 = "two"
   UserForm1.TextBox3 = "three"
   UserForm1.TextBox4 = "four"
   
   Dim cc As ContentControl
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim ccLocation  As Range

   For i = 4 To 1 Step -1  'Insert in reverse order to ensure that they are correct in the document
      Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Paste").Range
      rng.InsertAfter Text:="Number: "
      rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      Set ccLocation = rng.Duplicate
      rng.InsertAfter vbCr & "----------------------------------------" & vbCr
      Set cc = ccLocation.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
      cc.Range.Text = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & i).Text
      cc.Title = "Number" & i
   Next i

End Sub
```

If you cannot delete the existing content and must work with what you have then you could use the following:

```
Private Sub Test()

   Dim i As Integer

   UserForm1.TextBox1 = "one"
   UserForm1.TextBox2 = "two"
   UserForm1.TextBox3 = "three"
   UserForm1.TextBox4 = "four"
   
   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Number").Item(i).Range.Text = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox1").Text

   Dim cc As ContentControl
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim ccLocation  As Range

   For i = 4 To 2 Step -1  'Insert in reverse order to ensure that they are correct in the document
      Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Paste").Range
      rng.InsertAfter Text:="Number: "
      rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      Set ccLocation = rng.Duplicate
      rng.InsertAfter vbCr & "----------------------------------------" & vbCr
      Set cc = ccLocation.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
      cc.Range.Text = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & i).Text
      cc.Title = "Number" & i
   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the final document there are actually two content control fields (due to layout: each page contains two paragraphs with one content control field each) so I'll have to think about if your method is feasible or not. Still, the idea of adding the content control manually might be something I can use.

Comment: I can't quite figure out the code, I am afraid to say. Can you explain to me what the line "rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd" does? Does it set the focus to the end of what was just inserted (after "Number: ")? And what is there Duplicate there for? Why does it have to be at this particular position? Thanks for all your effort!

Comment: If there are properties or methods you are unfamiliar with I suggest you look them up in the online help. The [`Duplicate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.duplicate) is there to create an independent copy of the range so that the content control is inserted in the correct position. [`Collapse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.collapse) sets the start and end point of the `Range` to the end of the just inserted text.

Comment: I looked it up but I did not completely understand what copying the range meant. If I understand it correctly now, it means that the current range (at the end of the last insertion) is copied so that it can be accessed later, when the original range is changed due to the insertion of the additional text. Thanks for your help! I'll test the code some more the next days.